# Which forces constitute rolling friction?

Tags: friction

I am confused about rolling friction. When a wheel rolls, there is instantaneous static friction at the point the wheel touches the ground. This static friction is responsible for the wheel to roll and move forward. At the same time, is that friction wasn't present, the wheel would spin without rolling. Is this force the rolling friction? If yes, why we say that rolling friction opposes rolling then, as we saw it actually facilitates it? Also, I read that rolling friction makes a wheel decelerate as it rolls, how can that happen, as the friction actually facilitates rolling? In case the friction I previously described is not the rolling friction, which forces exactly constitute the rolling friction? And my professor said that rolling friction is actually dynamic and not static friction, how can that be since when a wheel rolls, the surface of the wheel that touches the ground is not moving (grips to the ground) in relation to the ground? If that grip is not efficient enough, then the wheel spins and doesn't roll. Please elaborate.